# Tkinter (binding a key to a button)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have a convert button in Tkinter - I want to make it so as that when the user presses the convert button and/or when user presses Enter/Return key the result is generated.

For some reason, I can't get the Enter/Return to bind to anything. I have linked it to master, `Label`/`Entry` but it doesn't seem to work. I am not getting any errors but it just isn't doing anything.

This is how I am doing it - Any ideas?

```
b = Button(master, text='convert', command=passwordgen)
b.bind('<Return>', passwordgen)
b.grid(row=5, column=1, sticky=W)
```

Comment: See above link. The accepted demonstrates that you should not bind to the button (`b`) but to the root window (`master`). That works as expected.

Comment: And of course, you have press enter in the GUI window, not in the Python console.